# Objective c - adding threading to UIView animation method results in only one animation running

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, animation

I've written a method, sortAndSlideHandCards(), that moves 6 UIButtons. Each UIButton is moved to the same position. This is done via a for-each loop and the animateWithDuration method being called on each UIButton.

This method is called for a number of players at the same time. Currently the behaviour results in UIButtons from each player moving but only one at a time. No more than one UIButton can move at any time, as if each animation is waiting for whatever animation that is currently running to stop before attempting it's own animation, essentially the code is executed sequentially for each player/UIButton. I hoped threading would help me fix this.

when I added the threading code:

```
backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);     
sortAndSlideHandCardsGroup = dispatch_group_create();

for(Player* player in _playersArray) {

    dispatch_group_async(sortAndSlideHandCardsGroup, backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
        [player sortAndSlideHandCards];
    });    

    dispatch_group_wait(sortAndSlideHandCardsGroup,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

I found that only the first UIButton animation is triggered for each player and that the code gets held up in the runloop "while" because "_animationEnd" never gets set as it would appear the second animation never gets going.

I can see the method launching in its own thread

```
- (void) sortAndSlideHandCards  {

NSLog(@"PLAYER:sortAndSlideHandCards");

CGPoint newCenter;
Card* tempCard = nil;
int count = 1;

float duration = 0.2 / _speedMultiplyer;
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
for(Card *card in _handCards) { //move cards in hand to one postion in hand

    if(count == 1) {
        tempCard = [[Card alloc] init:_screenWidth:_screenHeight :[card getNumber] :[card getCardWeight] :[card getSuit] :[card getIsSpecial]];
        [tempCard setImageSrc: _playerNumber :!_isPlayerOnPhone :count : true :_view: _isAI: [_handCards count]];
        newCenter = [tempCard getButton].center;
    }

    _animationStillRunning = true;
    if(![[DealViewController getCardsInPlayArray] containsObject:card] ) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{[card getButton].center = newCenter;} completion:^(BOOL finished){[self animationEnd];}];            
        while (_animationStillRunning){ //endAnimation will set _animationStillRunning to false when called
            //stuck in here after first UIButton when threading code is in play
            [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
        } //endAnimation will set _animationStillRunning to false when called

    }

    count++;
}
```

}

When i comment out the threading code each UIButton (Card) will animate one after another.

With the threading code is in play the first UIButton will animate but during the second run through the for-loop, the code will be stuck in the while-loop, waiting for the animation to end. I'm guessing the second animation doesn't even start.

I also tried this for the threading code:

```
[player performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sortAndSlideHandCards) withObject:nil];
```

Same outcome

Anyone have any ideas why animateWithDuration doesn't like getting called in a loop when in a thread other than the main one?

Comment: If I should be doing this work in the main thread then I'll go back and see if I can rewrite it.

Each player is dealt 6 cards, this method sorts the cards by moving all cards on top of one card and then spreading them back out in order. The method is part of the "Player" Class. Several players will all try and sort their cards at once. I'm trying to change the code so that each player runs this method in it's own thread so that the animations don't have to run one after another

I appreciate any pointers

Comment: Sure, but if I don't want the second card to move until the fist card has stopped moving I do need to wait until its finished. I could nest the 6 animations but that seemed untidy, if its not possible to do what I'm trying to do with a loop then I guess I'll change it to the nested animation blocks

Comment: Just thinking a bit ahead, this method is called further into the game when the player can have any number of cards. I cant nest the animations if i dont know how many there will be. This is why the loop is necessary. Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: I've added an answer, these comments were getting long and I think I've worked out what you want now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to kick off the animations you want from whatever UI action is performed. The UIView animateWith... methods return immediately, so you don't need to worry about waiting for them to complete.

If you have an unknown number of animations to kick off sequentially, use the `delay` parameter. Pseudocode:

```
NSTimeInterval delay = 0;
NSTimeInterval duration = 0.25;

for (UIView *view in viewsToAnimate)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay animations:^{ ... animations ...}];
    delay += duration;
}
```

This will increase the delay for each successive animation, so it starts at the end of the previous one.

Comment: That would solve my issue, only the next step is to spread the cards back out in order, and to do that i reorder an array and then start 6 more animations, again i need a runloop to monitor the previous step before starting the next one. I cant believe this is turning out to be so tricky

I'm thinking i need to completely change how i'm coming at this problem. All i want to do is allow 4 players to animate 6 cards each at the same time. That is, 1 method with animation code running for each user concurrently. If you had to approach an issue like this how would you do it? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd just put something like the above inside another loop, with one iteration per player or something. And perhaps start the next one in the completion block of the first. As I say, the animations run concurrently anyway, you don't need to (and can't) have separate threads or run loops for them.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out, instead of iterating through the players and then the cards i needed to iterate through the first card of every player then the second and so on. Thanks for the advice. Had the loops nested the wrong way around